# Rewriting Vector Equality

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces, vectors

I rewrote a vector equation and am searching for feedback if I did it properly.

I start with:

$\sum_{k=1}^N \lvert{<v,e_k>}\rvert^2=\alpha \Vert{v}\Vert^2$

where $v,e_k \in \mathbb{R}^5$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
I want to have a simple way to show that the equality above holds for a given set of $e_k$, independent of $v$.

I do the following:

$<=>\sum_{k=1}^N \lvert{<v,e_k>}\rvert^2=\alpha \Vert{v}\Vert^2$

$<=>\sum_{k=1}^N (v*e_k^T)^2=\alpha \sqrt{v^2}^2$

$<=>v^2 \sum_{k=1}^N (e_k^T) ^2 =\alpha v^2$

$<=>\sum_{k=1}^N (e_k^T) ^2  = \alpha$

Is this correct? I am not 100% certain about the way I move $v$ around given it is a vector that does not commute necessarily.

Comment: Observe $\lvert{<v,e_k>}\rvert^2  = \Vert{v}\Vert^2 \Vert{e_k}\Vert^2 \cos^2(\phi) $ where $\phi$ is the angle between the vectors $v$ and $e_k$. So your derivation does not hold.

Comment: As $v$ is a vector, $v^2$ makes no sense.

Comment: I suppose the $e_k$ are supposed to be the standard basis? Then $\alpha = 1$ would be right independent of $v$, but that can not just be shown with rewriting the equality, you need some insight on what $e_k$ are and what they have to do with the scalar product.

Comment: I see, so I made some mistakes above. In fact $e_k$ are not the standard basis, in this case they are some frame that is not necessarily orthogonal. For the sake of simplicity it is also OK to assume $\alpha=1$.

Comment: It would be great if someone could give me some hints on how to arrive at a similar point as described above, but then in the correct way :-)

Comment: The scalar products $<v,e_k>$ have to be evaluated (to do so, choose a representation of the vectors $e_k$ and $v$ in some basis, preferrably an orthonormal one). There is no way of avoiding this  since this depends on the angle (see my comment above). Further, it is easy to evaluate $\Vert{v}\Vert^2$ if $v$ is given in some orthonormal basis since then, $\Vert{v}\Vert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^5 v_i^2$ where the $v_i$ are the components of $v$ in that basis.  Then, $\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^N \lvert{<v,e_k>}\rvert^2 / \sum_{i=1}^5 v_i^2$. But I'm not sure if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I think this is what I want. I am now puzzled about your choice of representation remark. $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5)$, representing any possible vector in $\mathbb{R}^5$. So can you explain what a representation means? I would just go about and calculate what you wrote in a straightforward manner. Meaning: $|⟨v,e_1⟩|2=|(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5)⋅(e_{1,1},e_{1,2},e_{1,3},e_{1,4},e_{1,5})|2$

Comment: Observe  that a vector "lives" in a vector space independent of the basis you choose for describing that space. E.g. the relation already used, $\lvert{<v,e>}\rvert^2  = \Vert{v}\Vert^2 \Vert{e}\Vert^2 \cos^2(\phi)$, is written down without specifying any basis.  By "representation" I mean exactly that you choose a basis, typically the most convenient one. Then you wrote down the answer already. E.g. $e_{1,3}$ is the third component of vector $e_1$ in some orthonormal basis, and $v_{3}$ is the third component of vector $v$ in the same orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

In a compact form: $\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^N  \Vert{e_k}\Vert^2 \cos^2(\phi_k)$ where $\phi_k$ is the angle between the vectors $v$ and $e_k$.

Comment: Very concise, I understand. Assuming I have a number of $v_m$ and a given set of $e_k$, is it sufficient to show this for one nonzero $v_M$, or does it have to be shown for any vector $v_m$ and if so, how would this be done without calculating them one by one?

Comment: $\alpha$ is dependent on $v$, since on the RHS you need the angles between the vectors $v$ and $e_k$. So choosing a different $v$ will lead to a different $\alpha$.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Would anything change if we assume $\alpha=1$ and I am only interested in how far away $e_k$ is from satisfying the equality?